# Python 3.5.2 - Flask 0.12 on Windows - Cannot create a consistent method resolution order

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying the basic sample Flask application from their website,

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
   return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

but I'm getting the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/david.betteridge/Desktop/w.py", line 9, in <module>
app.run()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",     

line 827, in run from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", 
line 533, in <module>

class ForkingWSGIServer(ForkingMixIn, BaseWSGIServer): 
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) 
for bases BaseWSGIServer, object
```

I've looked up the Cannot create a consistent method resolution order error message and it suggests that the issue occurs when your class inherits from multiple classes,  and one of those classes inherits from the other one.

I haven't used Flask before,  so could the problem be related to the way it's installed.  (I used pip to install it).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue surfaced in Werkzeug 0.11. See [this](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/984) ticket discussion for details. Upgrading to Werkzeug 0.11.15+ should solve it:

```
pip install werkzeug --upgrade
```